# Arduino/Atmel Output Assembly?

Tags: arduino, avr, assembly

One thing I do not understand in reading about doing Assembly with the Atmel AVR (or perhaps with Arduino platform) is the actual outputting to devices (like LEDS/motors) and such.
Most Assembly "tutorials" simply explain counting/numeric stuff with registers.

Can anyone explain how exactly you send an out signal to a motor or LED under AVR assembly?

I guess I dont exactly get what each "pin" does for the microcontroller, and which ones can send output signals. (to turn a motor or led)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AVR, like most microcontrollers, uses [memory-mapped IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).  In a nutshell, this means that a part of the memory space of the microcontroller is reserved for the peripherals.  When you change a bit in this area of memory, you're not sending a signal to change a bit of memory, you're sending a signal to change the value of a peripheral.

To understand the details of how this works on your AVR, the [Special Function Registers](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sfr.html) section of AVR-libc (and, more importantly, sfr_defs.h and iom328p.h) are recommended reading.

[Warning: Technical writing ahead, pay close attention] For example, `PORTB` is defined as `_SFR_IO8(0x05)` in `iom328p.h`.  In `sfr_defs.h`, `_SFR_IO8(io_addr)` is defined as `_MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)`.  `__SFR_OFFSET` is `0x20`, the location just after the registers.  The space after this address and before `RAMSTART (0x100)` is used for the peripherals.  Going back to our example, `_MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr)` is defined as `(*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))`.  Therefore, when you write `PORTB`, you're really writing `*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x25)`, which defines a byte-wide pointer to the location in memory `0x25`. [/Warning]

So, when  (in C) you write PORTB |= 0x01, you're really writing the value 1 to the peripheral at byte 0x25, or port B pin 0.  If this pin is configured as output (using DDRB, which is at 0x24), PORTB |= 0x01 will cause port B pin 0 to go high.  Phew!

So, if you use the assembly instructions (SBI - Set Bit in I/O Register):

```
sbi  0x24,1 ;Data direction set to output
sbi  0x25,1 ;Set port B pin 0 high
```

You'll set the pin high.

Of course, use inline assembler with GCC and `#include <avr/io.h>` to get the conventional names and simplify your task.

Note that *all* of the peripherals use this scheme, not just the IO pins.  Read iom328p.h if you're interested in the locations of other peripherals.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    #define LED PB3

    sbi    DDRB,LED     ;PB3 output (LED)

loop:
    sbi     PORTB,LED       ;LED on
    rcall   dly
    cbi     PORTB,LED       ;LED off
    rcall   dly
    rjmp    loop
```

I've left out a lot of other stuff that is needed for a working program.

Answer (score 0):

```
.device ATmega168
.equ  DDRB       = 0x04
.equ  PORTB      = 0x05

.org 0x0000
    rjmp RESET

RESET:
    ldi R16,0x20
    out DDRB,R16

    ldi R18,0x00
    ldi R17,0x00
    ldi R20,0x20
Loop:

    ldi R19,0xE8
aloop:
    inc R17
    cpi R17,0x00
    brne aloop

    inc R18
    cpi R18,0x00
    brne aloop

    inc R19
    cpi R19,0x00
    brne aloop

    eor R16,R20
    out PORTB, R16
    rjmp Loop
```